# Increase number of recently closed tab items in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Is there a way to increase "recently closed tab" items in google chrome.

As of now it shows 10 items by default. But I want to display 50 items.

Comment: Recycle Bin (from the only answer below) no longer exists, whereas Web Recycle Bin (from a comment to that answer) still exists but is only used by a few hundred people. Any other good plugins for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for now Google Chrome natively supports the re-opening of up to 10 tabs only. The good news though is that you can use a plugin for Chrome which can remember more than 10.

The [Recycle Bin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recycle-bin/ikfbchidonfnclempkcojlpijhmoalhi?hl=en) plugin works well even across multiple windows but there are [several other options](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recycle-bin/ikfbchidonfnclempkcojlpijhmoalhi/related?hl=en) too.

Comment: Those links are gone, but I just installed the [Web Recycle Bin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-recycle-bin/neabikjncmoneefeceheidhfceoomjod/related) and looks like a solution so far...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I just discovered an improvement on what Raphael did (see below)

> A workaround without any extensions that doesn't show 50 tabs at a time, but can retrieve tabs beyond the 10th position:

> If you click on an item from the recently closed tabs list (Menu > History > Recently closed), the tab will open and it'll be removed from the list and give space for the next item to be shown. Repeat this process until you find the tabs that you need.

with a REALLY important subtlety (for me at least). If you keep pressed the Control Key when you're clicking on tabs/windows on the recently closed menu, they will open in your window without closing the menu, which means you can reopen and go back lots of windows really fast. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

A workaround without any extensions that doesn't show 50 tabs at a time, but can retrieve tabs beyond the 10th position:

If you click on an item from the recently closed tabs list (Menu > History > Recently closed), the tab will open and it'll be removed from the list and give space for the next item to be shown. Repeat this process until you find the tabs that you need.

Comment: This works, but only to about the 20th position, as far as I can tell.  After that, clicking on items from the recently closed tabs list will just make the list shorter.